# Issues between Action Support, Rerender, and SelectOptions

Tags: apex, visualforce

I started using field sets to allow a visualforce page be more customizable without having to deploy more code. Problem I'm seeing is that once I use an action support to rerender just a field, it will not reach out back to the apex class to pull in the proper information. I can probably get this to work just fine using Javascript Remoting, but I would like to understand why this is happening.

**Issue:** The page seems to be reloading list of fields from the fieldset rather than calling the method I have defined within my apex class.

The final goal is for the section (code snippet from VF section) to show Sobjects, and when an Sobject is pick, to show the fields that user can see. When a field is picked, the 3rd field will populate with the API merge value.

```
<!-- Custom Sobject PickList -->                
                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedSobject}" size="1" id="selectedSobject" rendered="{!AND(i.fieldPath == 'SobjectsList__c')}" >
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!sobjectList}" />    
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="selectedField" status="populateFieldStatus"/>                       
                </apex:selectList>
<!-- Custom Field PickList -->
                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedField}" size="1" id="selectedField" onchange="changeMergeFieldValue(this);" rendered="{!AND(i.fieldPath == 'FieldsList__c')}" >
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!SobjectFields}" />    
                </apex:selectList>
<!-- Custom Merge Field Value -->
                <apex:inputText value="{!mergeFieldValue}" id="mergeField" rendered="{!AND(i.fieldPath == 'MergeFieldValue__c')}" />
```

---

**Code currently being used below**

---

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Template__c" extensions="SobjectTemplate_Controller">
<head>
    <style>   
         input[type="text"] { width:300px; }
         select { width: 300px; }
    </style>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI, '/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js')}" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready(function(){
            // stuff goes here if you need to wait for DOM load
        });

        function changeMergeFieldValue(input){
            var sobjectValue = j$("[id*='selectedSobject']").val();
            var fieldValue = input.value;  
            // NOTE: Salesforce seems to search for '{' and '!' together, when executing server side logic
            // due to this I need to separate them hence why it's '{' + '!'          
            j$("[id*='mergeField']").val('{' + '!' + sobjectValue + '.' + fieldValue + '}');
            j$("[id*='mergeField']").select();
        }

        function disableSobjectFieldAccess(){
            j$("[id*='selectedField']").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
            j$("[id*='selectedField']").css('background', '#dddddd');
        }

        function enableSobjectFieldAccess(){
            j$("[id*='selectedField']").removeAttr("disabled");
            j$("[id*='selectedField']").css('background', '');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Header -->
    <apex:sectionHeader title="{!$ObjectType.Template__c.Label}" subtitle="{!record.Name}"/>
    <apex:actionStatus id="populateFieldStatus" onstart="disableSobjectFieldAccess();" onstop="enableSobjectFieldAccess();"/>

<!-- Error Message -->
    <apex:outputPanel id="msg"> 
        <apex:pageMessages /> 
    </apex:outputPanel>

<!-- Form -->
    <apex:form id="theForm">        
        <apex:pageBlock title="Template Edit">  
<!-- Standard Buttons -->
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" rerender="msg,information,templateSubject"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

<!-- TEST CODE -->        
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Details" columns="1" >
            <apex:repeat value="{!customFieldSet}" var="i">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    {!i.label}
                    <apex:outputPanel >
        <!-- Standard Field Inputs -->
                        <apex:inputField value="{!record[i.fieldPath]}" required="{!OR(i.required, i.dbrequired)}" rendered="{!AND(i.fieldPath != 'SobjectsList__c', i.fieldPath != 'FieldsList__c', i.fieldPath != 'MergeFieldValue__c')}"  />
        <!-- Custom Sobject PickList -->                
                        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedSobject}" size="1" id="selectedSobject" rendered="{!AND(i.fieldPath == 'SobjectsList__c')}" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!sobjectList}" />    
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="selectedField" status="populateFieldStatus"/>                       
                        </apex:selectList>
        <!-- Custom Field PickList -->
                        <apex:selectList value="{!selectedField}" size="1" id="selectedField" onchange="changeMergeFieldValue(this);" rendered="{!AND(i.fieldPath == 'FieldsList__c')}" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!SobjectFields}" />    
                        </apex:selectList>
        <!-- Custom Merge Field Value -->
                        <apex:inputText value="{!mergeFieldValue}" id="mergeField" rendered="{!AND(i.fieldPath == 'MergeFieldValue__c')}" />
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>  
<!-- END TEST CODE -->               
        </apex:pageBlock>         
    </apex:form>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class SobjectTemplate_Controller {

    private transient Map<String, Schema.DescribesObjectResult> sobjectMap = CommonSObjectMethods.getSobjectNameAndSobjectDescribe();
    private transient Map<String, Schema.Sobjectfield> sobjectFieldMap;

    private List<SelectOption> sobjectList;
    private Set<String> allowedSobjects = new Set<String>{'Account', 'Campaign', 'Contact', 'Lead', 'Opportunity', 'Resort__c', 'RoomType__c', 'User'};
    public transient String selectedSobject       { get;set; }
    public transient String selectedField         { get;set; }
    public transient String mergeFieldValue       { get;set; }
    public Template__c record           { get;set; }

    public SobjectTemplate_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.record = (Template__c)CommonSObjectMethods.getRecord(Schema.SObjectType.Template__c.getName(), controller.getId());
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getSobjectList(){
        if(null == sobjectList) setSobjectList();
        return this.sobjectList;
    }

    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getCustomFieldSet(){
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
        Schema.SObjectType SObjectTypeObj = GlobalDescribeMap.get(ObjectName);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult DescribeSObjectResultObj = SObjectTypeObj.getDescribe();

        // make sure to use correct fieldset name here
        Schema.FieldSet fieldSetObj = DescribeSObjectResultObj.FieldSets.getMap().get('FIELDSETNAME');
        return fieldSetObj.getFields(); 
    }

    private void setSobjectList(){
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('',''));
        List<String> sobjectAPIName = new List<String>(sobjectMap.keySet());
        sobjectAPIName.sort();
        for(String s :sobjectAPIName){
            if(allowedSobjects.contains(s)){
                Schema.DescribesObjectResult result = sobjectMap.get(s);            
                options.add(new SelectOption(s,result.getLabel()));
            }
        }
        this.sobjectList = options; 
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getSobjectFields(){
        selectedField = '';
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('',''));
        if(null == selectedSobject || '' == selectedSobject) return options;

        Schema.DescribesObjectResult sobjectMetaData = CommonSObjectMethods.getSobjectNameAndSobjectDescribe().get(selectedSobject);       
        sobjectFieldMap = sobjectMetaData.fields.getMap(); 
        List<String> sobjectFieldAPIName = new List<String>(sobjectFieldMap.keySet());
        sobjectFieldAPIName.sort();
        for(String s :sobjectFieldAPIName){
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = sobjectFieldMap.get(s).getDescribe();
            if(fieldResult.isAccessible())
                options.add(new SelectOption(s,fieldResult.getLabel()));
        }

        return options;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what exactly is not working, but one simplification is to get ride of the `sobjectMap` transient and move its declaration and initialisation to with the `setSobjectList` method. That removes any doubt about its value when the rerender is done. The `sobjectFieldMap` transient also appears to have no purpose and can be moved to the `getSobjectFields`.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, but the issue is when you pick a value which is set to the sobjectMap, the picklist values for SobjectFields are not being pulled back from the controller on the rerender. It doesn't even touch the method getSobjectFields() at all

Comment: In your test code, you are trying to rerender a component inside an apex:repeat. Did you try rerendering the pageBlockSection instead?

Comment: @crop1645, I tried to render both the pageBlockSection and the item itself, what seems to happen is the getter for the variable which is the list is called instead. I have no idea why that is happening.

Comment: There's too much going on here for me to wade through but I'd suggest the following (0) Simplify your VF page to the essence of the issue to resolve the rerendering; (1) Don't try and rerender a cell using its id as there are many rows with an SFDC-generated ID containing the rerender= value; rerender the pageblocksection (2) Use an inner class in the controller across the various lists to decide whether to display a row/cell;  (3) [alternative to 2), use JS remoting and do all the work in javascript with controller just being a data source

Comment: @crop1645 which is completely understandable, I redid it using JS Remoting, I just don't understand why it was refreshing the entire repeat section rather than the input field I was only attempting to do. It was working just fine until I introduced the functionality with fieldSets.

Comment: I am having the same problem, and it seems it's an issue with the transient keyword. If I put transient to a variable rendered inside the form of the VF page, any action that rerenders a block, which invokes a controller method, won't reach that method, instead will only rerender some stuff in the page.